# FIrebase Simple Login custom form

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase

Is it possible with firebase simple login to not redirect to a browser window on the app when asking for credentials, and instead use my own form? To keep consistency on the design.

Comment: Do you mean email&password login?

Comment: Only social logins (optionally) redirect to external window... Please specify if using Firebase 1.0 or 1.1, APIs changed a bit..

Comment: yes, right now in my app i click to login through facebook and the app opens a a browser window. is it possible to use my form?

Comment: 1.1.3 firebase, I saw Auth0, can that be a solution?

Comment: @DiogoBarroso Are you asking if you can create your own UI for Facebook login? Do you have an example of the flow you're trying to emulate, or what you're trying to change?

Comment: I'm starting to understand i don't fully grasp the concepts here. I was just wondering if it you be possible to communicate with Facebook servers through my own form. answering your question yes, I want my own UI for Facebook login instead of redirecting to Facebook page. But I was reading a bit more today and as I understand with social login you go to the social page then redirected to "my" page again.